# SwipeGesture not working while hold and press UIButton and drag to View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I implementing whatsapp like voice memo recording view all is working fine but I am not able dismissing this view on swipe to left . I have added UISwipeGesture and set direction to Left to the self.viewRecordVoice memo but its not working and calling swipeGesture target method below is my code but leftSwipeRecordView method never calling. I have googled a lot . 
Below I have attached screenshot that is while recording voice memo I want to call leftswipe method when user drag to left while hold and press mic.

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeGuesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeRecordView:)];
    swipeGuesture.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.viewRecordVoice addGestureRecognizer:swipeGuesture];
    self.viewRecordVoice.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    swipeGuesture.cancelsTouchesInView=YES;
    swipeGuesture.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
- (void)leftSwipeRecordView:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Swiped left");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why dnt you use Pangesture instead

Comment: Your code is perfect, might be possible there is some other control taking user interaction and viewRecordVoice is behind it. Check your view hierarchy once.

Comment: Might be the micButton causing problem because its been press and hold along with dragging (swiping) from view

Comment: @Kiran thanks It works fine with Pangesture